# Why is the Windows Features window showing PowerShell 2.0 installed?

Tags: windows-8, powershell-3.0

I'm running a Windows 8 machine. The "Windows Features" window tells my that I'm using PowerShell 2, but the PowerShell environment itself says otherwise, see screenshot below.

Why is the Windows Features window saying I got PowerShell 2.0?

[image: Screenshot of "PowerShell $psversiontable" and "Windows Features (expanded PS-node)"]

Comment: Helps if you expand what features are included by `Windows Powershell 2.0` it sounds like both versions are installed.  Does this happen on a fresh `Windows 8` installation?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849675.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PowerShell v3 is build into Windows 8, you can not add/ remove it.
v2 is different story - it's optional, system will operate normally without it, so you can disable/ enable it. To use it - you need to run `powershell.exe` with parameter `-version 2` - it should be first parameter on the list for it to work.